# If $\vec{u} = \vec{r}/r$, find $\mathrm{div} ~(\nabla \vec{u})$?

Tags: vector-analysis

If $\vec{u} = \vec{r}/r$,  find $\mathrm{div} ~(\nabla \vec{u})$.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What's the gradient of a vector? Is it a matrix, so that your desired result is a vector?

Comment: Did you mean $\nabla .{\vec u}$?

Comment: $\nabla\cdot\nabla = \nabla^{2}$ is the Laplacian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\nabla \vec u=\hat x_i\hat x_j\partial_i (u_j) \tag 1$$

Taking the divergence of $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \left(\nabla \vec u\right)&=\partial_i\left(\hat x_j\partial_i(u_j)\right)\\\\
&=\nabla^2\vec u\\\\
&=\nabla \nabla \cdot \vec u-\nabla \times \nabla \times \vec u
\end{align}$$

Then, we have for $r\ne 0$

$$\nabla \times \left(\frac{\vec r}{r}\right)=0$$

and

$$\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\vec r}{r}\right)=\frac{2}{r}$$

so that

$$\nabla^2 \left(\frac{\vec r}{r}\right)=-2\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: what does the tick mark mean ?

Comment: not in answer .

Comment: i found in the tour

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\,\mathrm{div}\pars{\nabla\pars{\vec{r} \over r}} = \nabla^{2}\pars{\vec{r} \over r}}$. You can use the identity:
>   
>   $\ds{\nabla^{2}\pars{ab} =
> \pars{\nabla^{2}a}b + 2\pars{\nabla a}\cdot\pars{\nabla b} + a\nabla^{2}b}$ which is a ' *sort of Newton Binomial* '.

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\nabla^{2}\pars{x \over r}} & =
\nabla^{2}\pars{x\,{1 \over r}}=
\pars{\nabla^{2}x}\,{1 \over r} +
2\pars{\nabla x}\cdot\nabla\pars{1 \over r} +
x\,\nabla^{2}\pars{1 \over r}
\\[4mm] & =
0 \times {1 \over r} +
2\,\hat{x}\cdot\pars{-\,{1 \over r^{2}}\,{\vec{r} \over r}} + x\bracks{-4\pi\delta\pars{\vec{r}}} =
\color{#f00}{-\,{2x \over r^{3}}}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\nabla\,\mathrm{f}\pars{r} = \,\mathrm{f}\,'\pars{r}\,{\vec{r} \over r}}$.

---

Similarly, for the $\ds{y}$ and $\ds{z}$ components:
$$
\color{#f00}{\nabla^{2}\pars{\vec{r} \over r}} = \color{#f00}{-\,{2\vec{r} \over r^{3}}}
$$

Comment: @orengan You're welcome.